# How to use less as a log file viewer?

Tags: shell, unix, logging, less-unix

I am trying to watch my log file with `less --follow-name +F MyLogFile.log`.

From the man page:

> If  --follow-name  is
>                 specified, during an F command less will periodically attempt
>                 to reopen the file by name.
>
> F          Scroll  forward, and keep trying to read when the end of file
>                 is reached.

So if I understand correctly, less should keep trying to read MyLogFile.log. However, when my program restarts and rewrites MyLogFile.log, less does not see the new file until I restart less. But shouldn't less be "periodically attempting to reopen the file by name"? I must be missing something here. How can I use less as a log viewer when I'm constantly restarting my program?

For reference, here is the full explanation of `--follow-name`, which seems to totally contradict what I am experiencing:

> Normally, if the input file is renamed while an F command  is
>                 executing,  less will continue to display the contents of the
>                 original file despite its name change.  If  --follow-name  is
>                 specified, during an F command less will periodically attempt
>                 to reopen the file by name.  If the reopen succeeds  and  the
>                 file  is a different file from the original (which means that
>                 a new file has been created with the same name as the  origi-
>                 nal  (now  renamed)  file), less will display the contents of
>                 that new file.

I am using less version 458 and OSX 10.12.4.

Comment: The easy answer is to append to your logs, rather than creating a new/different file.

Comment: BTW, `--follow-name` is only appropriate if it's a new and different inode. If it's just the old inode but truncated (which is the case with `yourprog >log`), that's not the case it's built to work in.

Comment: @Charles given the answer I just posted, does that mean that a new inode is only created when the file is deleted first?

Comment: Deleted, or if you create a new file and rename it over the current one.

Comment: btw, you can use `ls -i` or `stat yourfile` to see inode numbers.

Comment: @Charles That's interesting, I suppose I have to read up on what exactly inodes are.

Comment: (the design intent for `less --follow-name`, by the way, is to handle log rotation -- which typically looks something like `mv log.txt log-YYYYMMDD.txt; exec >log.txt`, replacing the directory entry pointing at the existing inode to have a new name, and then creating a new inode with the old name).

Comment: @Charles I never had a use for keeping previous logs yet, but I'm sure eventually it will come up. Thanks for all the info.

Answer (score 0):

**The file needs to be deleted before it's written in order for less to notice.**

I discovered this by running a little experiment with two terminal windows:

In the first I ran `less --follow-name file.txt` (file.txt already exists), while in the second I ran `echo text > file.txt`. Less did not notice. I tried again but this time I ran `rm file.txt` before `echo`, and it worked.

Thank you rubber ducky.